# Drupal 7 - renaming image in content will not update on page, but image is still displayed

Tags: drupal-7, file-rename

I have multiple Drupal 7 sites where images needs to be renamed. 
When i rename an image in admin/content/file - type=image, the image will rename properly but on the page where is used the image is not updated.

Is there any way renaming the images in admin/content by editing them one by one, and get them updated on each page where they are used, automatically ?

Ex: image name is "people-dancing.jpg" (used on 2 pages)
I renamed the image: "people-dancing-image.jpg"

After clear cache and opened in incognito, images on pages where they are used, still have the old name (the old img src url)

Any advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Unfortunately Drupal 7 will not allow you to rename images on the server. You must download them, delete them and upload them again with the proper name. The only solution.

Thanks